# How to pass positional parameters to a function

Tags: bash, shell

I was trying things with bash scripts. I made this simple script

```
#!/bin/bash

function myfun()
{
    for item in `seq 1 5`
    do
        echo "$item $1 $2"
    done
}
myfun
```

but no luck. If I change it like this as below, everything seems to be fine,

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$1
b=$2

function myfun()
{
    for item in `seq 1 5`
    do
        echo "$item $a $b"
    done
}
myfun
```

It looks like arguments (positional parameters) do not work inside function in shell. Am I doing any mistake? I am still learning things. So can you explain why is it so?

Comment: it isn't the loop - it is the function.  Inside a function $1 and $2 refer to the function's parameters and NOT to the script's parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a function, $1 and $2 give the function arguments and not the script parameters.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html

Answer (score 5):

It's the function not the loop:

```
function myfun()
{
    for item in `seq 1 5`
    do
        echo "$item $1 $2"
    done
}

# Pass all of the script's parameters to the function,
# as if writing  myfun "$1" "$2" "$3"..
myfun "$@"
```